# PySpark SQL and dangerous functions (e.g. access disk, access network, run forever)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm setting up a server that has some data on it coming from a variety of sources (mostly user submitted). The datasets will be stored on disk in a format readable by PySpark.

Now, I want to give users doing some queries on given datasets I want to give them access to, and I want to allow them through PySpark SQL.

However the first question that comes to my mind is, other than resources limitations issues (RAM, runtime etc..), what else should I worry about?

How can I prevent them from running queries such as:

- CREATE TABLE
- LOAD XYZ
- DUMP XYZ
- any other dangerous function you might think of?

I'm not planning setting up restrictions systems like chroot,kvm,ptrace env. Ideally we can do something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Permission the datasets on the disk to be read only for these users

Ideally, you will have scheduled jobs that creat your data. Users reading the data should almost always have read only access. Perhaps with the exception of some admins who use a separate admin account when they need to perform administrative operations

You should think about setting up user groups if you want different groups of people to have access to only certain datasets